# How to get all data from API in Power BI

Tags: api, powerbi, powerquery, offset, m

I'm following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904641/how-to-get-paginated-data-from-api-in-power-bi) to make a connection with pagination to an API (Marvel API as a study) by Power BI, and I realized that even generating a list with the number of API pages for each page, the same 20 records are requested.

Then I found [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616929/ios-marvel-api-how-to-get-all-characters) that talks about the `"offset"` and `"limit"` parameters, but I didn't understand the operation and how I should use it.

Get data> Web> API path
[image]

M language generated
[image]

Invoke function
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as follows: I created a list for the "offset" parameter of 100 in 100 and called the function passing this column in the "page" of the IPA URL

```
= List.Generate(()=>0, each _<=TOTAL_REGISTROS, each _+100)
```

[image]